# T-SQL code producing inconsistently erroneous values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

[image]
The above picture if a screen cap of the output from a report I've been making using t-SQL tables and views. Each column has two values the first being the current number and then following the forward slash is the difference value for each week. These numbers look great for most of my reports and yet as you can see the Total column seems to have a completely erroneous value for the difference.

This table was created using the following code

```
SELECT
   ISNULL(a.[LRPR Biospecimen Consent], 'Missing') AS Consent, 
   CONVERT(varchar, a.Oppong) + ' / ' + CONVERT(varchar, a.Oppong - ISNULL(b.Oppong, 0)) AS Oppong,
   CONVERT(varchar, a.Tousimis) + ' / ' + CONVERT(varchar, a.Tousimis - ISNULL(b.Tousimis, 0)) AS Tousimis,
   CONVERT(varchar, a.Willey) + ' / ' + CONVERT(varchar, a.Willey - ISNULL(b.Willey, 0)) AS Willey,
   CONVERT(varchar, a.Anderson) + ' / ' + CONVERT(varchar, a.Anderson - ISNULL(b.Anderson, 0)) AS Anderson, 
   CONVERT(varchar, a.Bacarra) + ' / ' + CONVERT(varchar, a.Bacarra - ISNULL(b.Bacarra, 0)) AS Bacarra,
   CONVERT(varchar, a.McMahon) + ' / ' + CONVERT(varchar, a.McMahon - ISNULL(b.McMahon, 0)) AS McMahon
FROM
   dbo.vw_RPT_Ourisman_BiospecimenConsentWithProvider_Pivot a 

   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl_vw_RPT_Ourisman_BiospecimenConsentWithProvider_Pivot b 
   ON ...
```

Variants of this code (with just pathnames changed has given accurate total values for the numbers on both sides of the forward slash.I am a novice SQL user and I just can't seem to figure out why this code has stopped working.

Any helpful advice is much appreciated

*EDIT*
Below is the code used to create the dbo.vw_RPT_Ourisman_BiospecimenConsentWithProvider_Pivot Total values.

```
 With T as ( SELECT     [LRPR Biospecimen Consent], [Oppong, Bridget A] AS Oppong,    [Tousimis, Eleni] AS Tousimis, [Willey, Shawna] AS Willey, [Anderson, Lyndsay] AS Anderson, 
                  [Bacarra, Minna Manalo] AS Bacarra, [McMahon, Ann] AS McMahon
FROM         vw_RPT_Ourisman_BiospecimenConsentWithProvider_List c PIVOT (count([Breast Provider]) FOR [Breast Provider] IN ([Oppong, Bridget A], [Tousimis, Eleni], 
                  [Willey, Shawna], [Anderson, Lyndsay], [Bacarra, Minna Manalo], [McMahon, Ann])) piv
WHERE     [LRPR Biospecimen Consent] IS NOT NULL)
SELECT     *
 FROM         T
UNION ALL
SELECT     'Total', SUM(Oppong), SUM(Tousimis), SUM(Willey), SUM(Anderson), SUM(Bacarra), SUM(McMahon)
FROM         T
```

Comment: If any of your returned data contains NULLs the results may not be as expected.

Comment: How are you calculating your total row?  Is 'Total' a value in LRPR Biospecimen Consent?  Or is it something you're doing in the report itself?  Why isn't there a 'Missing' row?  Are you filtering it out somehow?  Put the rest of your sql up there if you would.

Comment: BTW -- use better field names (short, no spaces) and table aliases per the edit to your post, and you'll have an easier time reading/formating your code.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and the edit. As you can see I am creating the totals using the pivot and sum functions. Hopefully I've made this a bit clearer for everyone. 

As for the missing row I apologize I realize that is just a filter for the larger case in which I use this generic sql code. In some of our columnns the values haven't been filled in and NULL counts are listed as missing if they appear.